# No visible interface for selector - for IBOutlet

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa

That's a weird one:

- I'm using a [DMSplitView](https://github.com/malcommac/DMSplitView) instance
- Dragging it to my `AppDelegate.h` which creates an outlet like `@property (weak) IBOutlet DMSplitView *verticalSplit;`

However, whenever I'm trying to access it, in my `AppDelegate.m`, I'm getting an error:

`No visible @interface for 'AppDelegate' declares the selector verticalSplit`

How is that possible? I've done that like 10,000 times before. What sort of bug is that? Any ideas?

---

**P.S.**  Just tried it as an experiment, and it's official: I cannot add *any* outlet whatsoever. :S

Comment: Odd...I'd be tempted to run AppDelegate.m through the preprocessor and see if anything was getting broken at that stage.

Comment: Are you using Xcode 6, NSStoryboards with a NSSplitViewController?

Comment: How many AppDelegate.h files do you have?

Answer (score -1):

How are you defining DMSplitView? Did you use the @class directive in the header file? Did you import it in the .m file? Just wondering.